# Can I download currently streaming songs from Clementine?

Tags: downloads, music, clementine

I use Clementine on 12.04 as an audio player. When I am typing something on the search bar, it searches my local music library as well as Internet. Sometimes it shows songs which are not in my music library. So, I want to download songs which are streaming from Internet (jamendo, Icecast, Google drive, UbuntuOne, Magnatune, JazzRadio, DI and much more). I can stream songs easily,but there is no option to download them to my computer. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

this is the command you need

```
xterm -e streamripper {tp} -d /media/storage/Music
```

please read this to understand it completely : [Groups.google.com](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/clementine-player/z5caA2d7iJE)

Comment: i assume, tp is for the address of server. But, how can i get the address of a particular streaming song?